# Minimize instead of Exit in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 App

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, background-process

I am developing a  Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 App.  Whenever the user is pressing BACK Key, it should Minimize/Close/Hide the App instead of Exiting/Quiting.

I mean, how to send the application to  background instead of quiting on pressing BACK Key?

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

By merely upgrading an app from 8.0 to 8.1 you get this behavior. This was a change since 8.0. See the documentation under "In-App navigation" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn632424.aspx]

Your app might still get killed though - if it uses too many resources and other apps needs them, the app will get shut down by the system.

Comment: Application.Current.Suspending += new SuspendingEventHandler(App_Suspending);
 is used in Windows Phone 8.1 Store app but, I am building a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app. Application.Current.Suspending does not exist in it